# Jquery click event on button without class or id

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have this button that I can't change, nor can I edit toCashier():

```
<input type="button" value="Till kassan" onclick="toCashier()">
```

And I want to track if it's clicked and execute some javascript.

```
$(document).ready ( function () {
    $('button[value="Till kassan"]').on('click', function(){
        alert("Night button clicked");
    });
});
```

I tried that but it doesn't seem to work. I tried various things but can't get it to work.

Comment: It seems odd to query elements based on their value. Instead I would query on an id: `$('#myButton')` and `<input id="myButton" />` might be a better approach.

Comment: Also, is `toCashier` defined?

Comment: whatever script you want to execute on this button click you can put that script in `toCashier()` function.

Comment: I can't change the button or access the toCashier() function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mismatched input and button, try the following :

```
$(document).ready ( function () {
   $('input[value="Till kassan"]').on('click', function(){
    alert("Night button clicked");
   });
});
```

Or

```
$(document).ready ( function () {
   $('input[type="button"][value="Till kassan"]').on('click', function(){
    alert("Night button clicked");
   });
});
```

Comment: That explains it! Thanks!

Comment: If your problem is fixed, please consider marking an answer as the solution, thanks

Comment: Yeah, just waiting for the timer. I see that I missed a `;` in the end as well.

Answer (score 1):

button !== input

You need to use the correct selector.

```
$('input[value="Till kassan"]')
```

Answer (score -1):

If you make the click with function, `toCashier()` function need to create :

```
function toCashier(){      
    alert("Night button clicked");    
}
```